# MongoDB Add Current Date in aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation-framework

How can I add a field in an Aggregation pipeline where I set the current date as the value (similar to `getdate()` in sql)

Comment: So did you try this :: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/ . FYI, dates in mongoDB defaults to UTC..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this :

FYI, dates in mongoDB defaults to UTC. Please check this :: [MongoDB-Date()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$addFields : {dateField : new Date()}}])
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e287d7ad02e05b694bcce8a"),
    "addingDate" : true
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e287d7ad02e05b694bcce8a"),
    "addingDate" : true,
    "dateField" : ISODate("2020-01-22T17:03:17.928Z") // In UTC
}
```

Just in case if you need to add local time, pass in your `time-zone` :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        dateField: {
            $dateToParts: { date: new Date(), timezone: "America/New_York" }
        }
    }
},
{
    $addFields: {
        dateField: {
            $dateFromParts: {
                'year': '$dateField.year', 'month': '$dateField.month', 'day': '$dateField.day',
                'hour': '$dateField.hour', 'minute': '$dateField.minute', 'second': '$dateField.second', 'millisecond': '$dateField.millisecond'
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e287d7ad02e05b694bcce8a"),
    "addingDate" : true,
    "dateField" : ISODate("2020-01-22T12:03:17.928Z") // Date in passed in time-zone
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I tried it on Mongo shell and it worked perfectly.  However when I try and do the same thing on Compass it is giving me the following error: "Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" found."

Comment: @RitienneGauci : Mongo compass has slightly different way of when paying queries, try it in robo3T another client for accessing mongo or try using mongo compasses aggregation query builder and input stages

Comment: **$$NOW** works in MongoDB Compass as well [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59863398/mongodb-add-current-date-in-aggregation-pipeline/68530496#68530496)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the **$$NOW** system variable in your aggregation pipeline as below
to insert the current datetime value

**Example**

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        _createdAt: '$$NOW'
    }
}])
```

**Reference**

1. [MongoDB Docs $$NOW](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.NOW)